# Python insert empty rows after each existing row using openpyxl/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to read and edit an excel file with multiple worksheets, but I need to edit only one sheet from that file keeping the other sheets intact. Knowing that I realized I should use openpyxl as it can edit an file without loosing the other contents so I started with the following:

```
        xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsm',  read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
        sheet = xfile['Main']
```

While this works but I need to also have a method/function to add three empty rows for all existing rows starting from index two. This is where I realized openpyxl might not be the perfect solution for this case as writing that many rows using openpyxl is not efficient. The a simple solution I could have thought of which definitely does not work as expected:

```
        for x in range (2, sheet.max_row):
             sheet.insert_rows(x,amount=5)
        xfile.save('text3.xlsm')
```

I would love to use pandas in this case but pandas would loose the other worksheets when it exports the data which wouldn't work for me. Any suggestions/guidance is highly appreciated.
For ease of understanding purpose I am providing a dummy data to showcase what i am trying to execute:

original file:

```
   Product Quantity
0  ignore   ignore
1  ignore   ignore
2   Apple    3
3   Orange   5
4   Banana   5
```

Expected output:

```
   Product Quantity
0  ignore   ignore
1  ignore   ignore
2   Apple    3
4    Nan      Nan
5    Nan      Nan
6    Nan      Nan
7   Orange   5
8   Nan      Nan
9   Nan      Nan
10  Nan      Nan
11   Banana   5
12    Nan      Nan
13    Nan      Nan
14    Nan      Nan
```

Thank you very much for reading through this problem statement.

Comment: I suspect pandas wouldn't do great at this either, since adding rows would cause the entire dataframe to be copied over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in openpyxl, and in the Python world, this is probably you're only option. But when adding / deleting rows and columns you need to remember than you are changing something while looping over it. So that if you insert 5 rows starting at row 3, your counter will subsequently be wrong.

The easiest way around this is to insert the rows from the bottom, because this means you don't have to worry about row numbers changing. But this is also the least efficient, because the cells in the new rows will also have to be renumbered every time you add new rows.

If you are only interested in the data then the best approach would be to work directly with a copy of the data, delete the rows in the sheet and then add the data from the copy.

```py
data = []
for row in ws.values:
    data.append(row)
    data.append([[]]*5)

title = ws.title
del wb[title] # or manually delete the relevant rows
ws = wb.create_sheet(title, x) # x is the index of the worksheet in the workbook

ws.append(["Product", "Quantity"]
for row in data:
    ws.append(row)
```

To do this with the worksheet you'll need to create a counter that matches the number of rows after you've created them. Say you've got 10 rows, then after the first insertion you will have 15, then 20, etc. == x + 5x

```
for i in range(2, ws.max_row * 5, 5): # you will be stepping 5 rows at a time
    ws.insert_rows(i, 5)
```

This is untested so will probably need some adjustment. I suggest you work on a simple dummy file to fine tune it.